# Why are the 'proc' and 'sys' folders more than 100 TB in size?

Tags: ubuntu

Someone I know just made the following statement:

> "I have 140.7 TB worth of files on my system"

Someone else said something along the lines of "how?" and the response was:

> "Virtual RAM, Ubuntu has its quirks. `/proc/core` file"

I don't know much about Linux and wondered if someone could explain what the above is all about. I don't get how anyone could have 140.7 TB worth of anything, unless they have a very large number of hard disks.

Comment: What appears to be a file is not necessarily a file on the hard disk. And files' logical size isn't always the same as their physical size (i.e. storage required).

Comment: I also have this 140.7 TB file. Byte size is 140737477881856. I wonder what that number means.

Comment: That number is near 2^47, which is 140.737.488.355.328.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

These locations belong to *virtual* filesystems. Everything you see – folders, files, their contents – is made up on the spot whenever you try to access it. The actual size isn't even known until *after* you read the file (and it often can't be cached as different readers may well see different contents).

The filesystems themselves occupy nothing at all; they're just views into the kernel.

Sometimes the size *is* known but the data it *represents* is massive. For example, the [`core`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic-core_memory) files represent the virtual address space of a process – and this address space is as large as the CPU can address; it is unbound by actual RAM/swap size. So the file will be somewhere around 2<sup>48</sup> to 2<sup>64</sup> bytes on a "64-bit" system.

So it's normal that you will get really strange numbers if you run disk usage utilities on virtual filesystems, especially if they count "apparent" (sparse) size, not the actual disk usage.

Answer (score 5):

No, that's not why. [Sparse files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file) *appear* a certain size because the file header lists it, but they *contain* far less data.

Comment: And amazing things happen when you try to back up sparse files with a backup program that doesn't understand them. Learned that on Xenix.

Answer (score 1):

One way *could* be that they have a large number of compressed files and are counting the size they would be when **uncompressed**.

Obviously this would depend on the type of file as some files compress further than others (e.g. text files) and others can't be compressed further (e.g. jpg, mp3) without losing data, but *theoretically* this could give the numbers your friend quotes.

Comment: Sure, if you had about 20TB of storage.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams - I'm not saying it's likely, just possible.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: That's just ten 2TB disks.

Comment: @grawity - full of text...

Comment: @ysap full of COMPRESSED text.